# Find the tangent between two points

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, solution-verification, tangent-line

Let $f(x) = x^3$. Show that for every point $P = (x_0, y_0) \in\mathbb R^2$ there is a tangent to the graph of $f(x)$ that passes through $P$.

I said in order for this to be true $f'(x)$ needs to be defined for all $f(x)$ and for all $x$'s. If this is true then we will have a value for all $f'(x)$. This means that $f(x)$ will be able to give us all types of straight lines that both grows and decreases. So I differentiated $f(x)$ to $3x^2$ and here we can see that $f'(x)$ is defined for all x's and thus there is a line for every $(x_0, y_0)$ that passes through the point $p$.

But in the answers they used mean value theorem etc, but I was wondering if my explanation was totally wrong because I got $0$ point on it.

Comment: Your answer is indeed wrong. Consider a much simpler function: $f(x) = 0$. This function is differentiable, but none of its tangent lines pass through the point $(0,1)$.

Comment: You said "This means that f(x) will be able to give us all types of straigt lines that both grows and decreases." Not only is this not a precise statement (what *exactly* does this sentence mean?), it is completely unjustified. Even worse, no matter how you try to interpret this claim precisely, it is wrong. To avoid problems like this, your mathematical explanations must be completely precise and completely justified.

Comment: It is not lucid what you mean by every point. Is $f(x_0)=y_0$? Please be more consistent with the notation.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is intuitive, and could be plausible with accompanying illustrations, but it isn't rigorous or convincing. If one of my students had answered that question that way, I would have given some credit for understanding the statement.

Every point on the graph of $f(x) = x^3$ will already have a tangent line through it, because the function is differentiable. If $P = (x_0,y_0)$ is *not* on the the graph, and $(x,x^3)$ *is* on the graph, then the line between them has slope $\frac{x^3-y_0}{x-x_0}$. That line is tangent to the graph of $f$ if the slope equals $f'(x) = 3x^2$.

So you are looking for a real number $x$ such that
$$
    \frac{x^3-y_0}{x-x_0} = 3x^2 \iff x^3 - y_0 = 3x^2(x-x_0)
    \iff 2x^3 - 3x^2 x_0 + y_0 = 0
$$
Every cubic polynomial has a real root, so we know some $x$ satisfies the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Considering

$$
\cases{
y = x^3\\
y = y_0+m(x-x_0)
}
$$

after substitution (on intersection) we have

$$
x^3 = y_0+m(x-x_0)
$$

but we need tangency so $m$ should be such that

$$
\phi_m(x)=x^3-(y_0+m(x-x_0))=(x-a)(x-b)^2
$$

meaning that $\phi_m(x)$ have a double root and as a consequence

$$
\cases{a b^2+m x_0-y_0=0\\ 2 a b+b^2+m=0\\ a+2 b=0}
$$

and after the elimination of $\{a,b\}$

$$
4m^3-27x_0^2m^2+54x_0y_0m-27y_0^2=0
$$

which means that there exists always a real root $m^*$ satisfying this polynomial.

NOTE

From
$$
\cases{2 a b+b^2+m=0\\ a+2 b=0}\Rightarrow \cases{b^2=\frac m3\\ b^3 =\frac{m x_0-y_0}{2}}\Rightarrow \left(\frac m3\right)^3 = \left(\frac{m x_0-y_0}{2}\right)^2
$$